# PHP: Detecting ID from a Scanned Document using Bubbled-In Numbers

Tags: php, image-processing, pixel, digits, scanning

I am working on a form that can be scanned in and uploaded to my server. I need a script (preferably PHP, but others are welcome) that can read in a 4-digit ID number from the form.

My current plan for the form is to have a table like this:

[image]

So, the plus marks show the boxes or bubbles that a person has filled in **using a pen**. In this example, the ID would be '2014.'

My question is, what is the best way to detect which digits have been filled in?

I assume I should color code the table so that I can find the rgb values within that color range so I know where the table starts and ends. Then I assume I could use the position of each box and check that area to see if the average values inside are above a given threshold.

Anyone done anything similar to this or have any advice / scripts that may help solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a barcode of a suitable format, and use a [library to read and decode the barcode](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode). I've linked [php-zbarcode](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode), which uses ImageMagick and [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) and can decode most barcode formats, including QR codes.

Comment: That would be great as I have worked with barcodes like this before, but the ID is filled in by hand. So barcodes wouldn't work here.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Missed the part of filling it in using a pen.